# How to efficiently 'query' multiple tsv files?

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv

I've got about 40 tsv files, with the size of any given tsv ranging from 250mb to 3GB. I'm looking to pull data from the tsvs where rows contain certain values.

My current approach is far from efficient:

```py
nums_to_look = ['23462346', '35641264', ... , '35169331']  # being about 40k values I'm interested in
all_tsv_files = glob.glob(PATH_TO_FILES + '*.tsv')

all_dfs = []
for file in all_tsv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')

    # Extract rows which match values in nums_to_look
    df = df[df['col_of_interest'].isin(nums_to_look)].reset_index(drop=True)

    all_dfs.append(df)
```

Surely there's a much more efficient way to do this without having to read in every single file fully, and go through the entire file?

Any thoughts / insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really. TSV is a *storage* format, not a database. If you plan on making multiple queries against the same data, it is worth the effort to read the data into a suitable data structure first, but for one-off queries, no, a linear scan is the best you can do.

Comment: Cheers @chepner. That makes sense. Any specific data structure worth going for?